# C# Computing the Mark Up Price using Profit Combobox SelectedIndex Property

Tags: c#

I am having an 'Input String was not in a correct format', this is the formula i use to copmute the price. cost + (cost*(profit/100)). and this is my code in the txtprofit_SelectedIndexChanged that gives me an Input String was not in a correct format.

```
try
        {
            //forprice
            txtPrice.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtcosting.Text) + (Convert.ToInt32(txtcosting.Text) * (Convert.ToInt32(txtprofit.Text) / 100))).ToString();

            //fordisplayingtheVatableSale
            vat.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(1.12)).ToString();

            //fordisplayingtheTax  
            tax.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(vat.Text)).ToString();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

This is the code that computes the Cost using the listview1_Mouseleave.

```
decimal sum = 0;
        foreach (ListViewItem xx in listView1.CheckedItems)
            sum += decimal.Parse(xx.SubItems[5].Text);
        txtcosting.Text = sum.ToString();
```

This is the design.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGp2B.png)

Comment: Which operation throws the exception?  What is the string you're trying to convert to a number when that happens?  The error is pretty clear... You're trying to parse a string into a numeric value, but that string does not represent a numeric value.  As a contrived example, what number would the string `"this is the number five"` represent?  You need to check your inputs.  You may also want to look at something like `decimel.TryParse()` for handling invalid inputs more cleanly.

Comment: from the 5th index of the listview, it contains the amount of the ingredients (their prices) from the database which has the data type of decimal(18,2). I'll try the decimal.TryParse and see for the result.

Comment: Keep in mind that parsing text to numeric data may also depend on the system culture, where things like decimal characters can be different.  More to the point however, you need to debug.  "It contains the amount of the ingredients" is a statement with a variety of assumptions.  "The value of the variable `x` at runtime is `"123.45"`" is specific.  Be specific, don't rely on assumptions.